# majorizing measures for small ball probabilities

Tags: reference-request, gaussian

This is a reference request. Can Majorizing measures be used to estimate small ball probabilities? Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. "estimate" is a very loose term, what exactly are you looking for? What situation specifically are you looking for? Since you write "ball", I assume that you have at least a metric space somewhere. Would the mass distribution principle (meaning the theorem $(\forall x\in X: \mu(B_r(x)) \leq C r^t)\implies (\forall A: \mu(A)\leq C\mathcal{H}^t(A))$ where $\mathcal{H}^t$ denotes the $t$-dimensional Hausdorff measure on $X$) something you'd like? In short: Please be more specific.

Comment: Not so much majorizing measures, but metric entropy is very closely related to small ball probabilities; the basic reference is Kuelbs-Li, JFA 1993. For a bibliography see http://www.proba.jussieu.fr/pageperso/smalldev/biblio.pdf